# How to pass the language in the options of the createFrom function in symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I would like to pass the language in the createForm function. In my Person Entity, I've 3 foreign keys to others entities. In hich entity, I've a field in French and an other in Dutch. So, I would like pass the language to choose the good field when I build the form.

My controller :

```
namespace RipliBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use RipliBundle\Entity\Person;
use RipliBundle\Form\PersonType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    //view a list of persons
    public function viewPersonAction()
    {     
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();                
        $person = $repository->getRepository('RipliBundle:Person')->findAll();
        return $this->render('RipliBundle:Person:viewPerson.html.twig', array(
            'person' => $person));
    }      
    
    /* 
     * add a person
     *    get the nationality entity of Belgium in db
     *    create a new person and set the nationality by default
     *    call the function to generate and view the form  
     *    if form submitted, persist in db  
     */
    public function addPersonAction(Request $request) {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                ->getRepository('RipliBundle:Nationality');
        $nationality = $repository->find(42);
        
        $person = new Person();
        $person->setNationality($nationality);
        return $this->formManagement($person, 'manage', $request);
    }
    
    /* 
     * modify a person
     *    get the person datas in db
     *    call the function to generate and view the form  
     *    if form submitted, persist in db  
     */
    public function modifyPersonAction($id, Request $request)
    {     
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();                
        $person = $repository->getRepository('RipliBundle:Person')->find($id);
        return $this->formManagement($person, 'manage', $request);
    }   
    
    /*
     * generate and view the form
     * if form submitted, persist in db  
     */
    private function formManagement($person, $actionView, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person, array('lang' => 'N'));
        
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($person);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Person saved successfully');
        }
        
        return $this->render('RipliBundle:Person:'.$actionView.'Person.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

My PersonType

```
namespace RipliBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {               
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('birthDate', BirthdayType::class,array(
                'years' => range(date('Y'), 1930),
                'format' => 'dd / MM / yyyy'
            ))
            ->add('nationality',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'RipliBundle:Nationality',
                'choice_label' => 'nationalityF',
                'label' => 'Nationality',
                'query_builder' => function(\RipliBundle\Repository\NationalityRepository $er){
                return $er->listNationalityActive();
                }
            ))
            ->add('sex',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'RipliBundle:Sex',
                'choice_label' => 'sexF',
                'label' => 'Sex',
                'placeholder' => '- - - -',
                'query_builder' => function(\RipliBundle\Repository\SexRepository $er){
                return $er->listSexActif();
                }
            ))
            ->add('language',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'RipliBundle:LanguagePerson',
                'choice_label' => 'languageF',
                'label' => 'Language',
                'placeholder' => '- - - -',
                'query_builder' => function(\RipliBundle\Repository\LanguagePersonRepository $er){
                return $er->listLanguageActive();
                }
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
        ;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RipliBundle\Entity\Person'
        ));
    }
}
```

And I would like to do

```
namespace RipliBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {               
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('birthDate', BirthdayType::class,array(
                'years' => range(date('Y'), 1930),
                'format' => 'dd / MM / yyyy'
            ))
            ->add('nationality',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'RipliBundle:Nationality',
                'choice_label' => 'nationality'.$option['lang'],
                'label' => 'Nationality',
                'query_builder' => function(\RipliBundle\Repository\NationalityRepository $er){
                return $er->listNationalityActive($option['lang']);
                }
            ))
            ->add('sex',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'RipliBundle:Sex',
                'choice_label' => 'sex'.$option['lang'],
                'label' => 'Sex',
                'placeholder' => '- - - -',
                'query_builder' => function(\RipliBundle\Repository\SexRepository $er){
                return $er->listSexActif($option['lang']);
                }
            ))
            ->add('language',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'RipliBundle:LanguagePerson',
                'choice_label' => 'language'.$option['lang'],
                'label' => 'Language',
                'placeholder' => '- - - -',
                'query_builder' => function(\RipliBundle\Repository\LanguagePersonRepository $er){
                return $er->listLanguageActive($option['lang']);
                }
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
        ;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RipliBundle\Entity\Person'
        ));
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what don't work in your solutions?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me, try $options rather than $option

Answer (score 2):

I've the solution

In the function configureOptions, I've added 'lang' => 'F' and that's ok

```
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RipliBundle\Entity\Person',
            'lang' => 'F'
        ));
    }
```